# View Controller interface and implemenations files in Cordova 2.1.0

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova

I installed the newly released phonegap(`cordova`) version `2.1.0` for `IOS` app development, and by default under `Classes dir`, both `AppDelegate` and `MainViewController`(containing view functions like `webViewDidFinishLoad`,`webViewDidStartLoad`,etc.) interface and implementation files came. Can i remove the `MainViewController` files and use only `AppDelegate` files for everything, like it used to be in `phonegap 1.3`.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks